# Native Plugin For Windows 8 Using Cordova

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am creating a windows8 plugin in cordova but i want to be integarte native build like .winmd with my plugin so that through Winjs i m calling the functions of that library which is in c#. I had already added the reference and code into plugin folder and as well as in project. But still it throws an error WinRt Error : class is not register/JavaScript Error : class in not defined.

I am creating same plugin in WP but there is issue in windows8 plugin development using cordova winjs with native functionality. please help to resolve this issue, provide some samples , links etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

It seems that to reference a WinRT component from a Cordova project using the current VS Tools for Cordova release, you need to follow the instructions here:

https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/11/24/using-windows-runtime-component-with-cordova-project/

In particular, section 1 describes how to inform the Cordova build tools about your WinRT component(s), so that it can reference it/them in the AppX manifest, and include the component binaries in the output package.

---

Earlier notes:

Do you need to actually write it as a Cordova plug-in? Windows JS apps support really simply integration of custom WinRT components, which can be written in C++ or C#. You just have to create a new Windows Runtime Component project in your solution, define a public sealed class with the methods/properties you want to expose, and then add a reference from your JS app project to the WinRT component (right-click References, select Add Reference, and choose the component project).

That said, be wary of the performance implications of including a C# component (particularly if you need to load it during startup) and the memory usage implications of loading the CLR and all the .NET dependencies. Also remember that C# is not "native" so it isn't really a "native plugin" if you do that :-)

You also might get slightly better advice if you describe your goal (i.e. you need the native plugin for something where you're actually running against JS performance limitations - which is a fairly exceptional case).

Comment: As you suggested me i had already done the same . But problem is still exist . Cordova Plugin didn't allow us to add reference of another c# code. It throws error of "Class is Undefined" even at the time of object creation.

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio Tools for Cordova? Is this VS 2013 or 2015 RC?

Comment: It looks like with the current Cordova Tools, you need to follow these instructions to tell the Cordova build system to include the WinMD/DLL and reference it correctly in the AppX manifest.

https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/11/24/using-windows-runtime-component-with-cordova-project/

Comment: I am using  Visual Studio Tools for Cordova 2013 . Which link you posted same link i had already followed . Each & everything goes fine but  when creating the object of winmd file then it throws error "undefined".